# What is eating my hdd on vps server after a few minutes?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, debian-squeeze

I installed iotop and I see a command that I don't understood and it uses 96-99% of my IO?

This is it:

```
find /var/www/virtual/webpult.hu -type f -path */phptmp/sess_* -cmin +24 -exec rm -v {} ;
```

I uploaded an image with screenshot of iotop and htop.

I installed debian squeeze and i-mscp. The page is webpult.hu , it runs prestashop.
[screenshot here](http://www.kepmegoszto.com/201411250815/f-54742c81ad16b-someerror.jpg)

Now, disk read is 8M/s 30 minutes after starting my server. The same TID eats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely coming from a cron job meant to eliminate old PHP session data from the web site in `/var/www/virtual/webpult.hu`.

You can speed this up considerably if you change this cron job to run `find` only in the location where the data is actually stored and not in the whole web tree.

Comment: I killed that in htop and now my server running quick. But I don't know how/where that cron starts again. I checked cron.d, cron daily, etc, but not found.

Comment: Try `crontab -l -u www-data` (or whichever user this app is running under).

Comment: or ls /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ , cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs